# How could I fix/remove the '0' number next to the chapter title in the header which has no number in Word for Windows?

Tags: microsoft-word, headers, numbering

I am writing my thesis and I have used Quick Parts > Field and ... to add the the chapter numbers and titles to the header automatically. I also have to mention I wrote it like a book and setting the Style to odd and even pages. my problem is that 'Abstract' of each chapter won't have number (the thesis foormat must be like this: a chapter get a number and title ,and each chapter will have i) 'abstract' without number and then 'introduction', 'results', 'discussions' and etc which each has a number). The problem is 'Abstract' is appearing with '0' zero number in header. I would so much appreciate it if someone could tell me how I can fix and remove 0 next to Abstract from Header.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Also, post online an example document.

Comment: What you have in your Header is a StyleRef Field. See Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's work  on useful styleref tricks http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/StyleRef.htm.